# Pay to flag a node with drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, flags

Please help achieve the folowing:
I have a content type "proposal" with a field "prépayment_amount". I want the user who try to flag this node to pay the amount indicated in the field "prepayment_amount" and when the payment is successful, I want to notify this to the user who created this node, if not the flag is cancelled.

Comment: What kind of technique, concept or Drupal procedure do you have in place to "find out" if a payment was successful or failed? Also, is the flagging user yes or no the same as the user who created the node?

Comment: I think, I have to use rules. No the user who flag the node is not the one he created it

Comment: OK, that is what I was assuming / guessing also. So your question is about the "flagging user" and the "author of the node". Can you also clarify what you mean with "when the payment is successful" (as in my prior comment)? Apart from that: "try to flag" a node is not something you can do in Drupal: you have a link to flag a node, or you just don't have such link. So I think you should assume the node "is" flagged. Does that make sense?

Comment: actually I am developing a freelancer marketplace, when a client posts a project, freelancers post proposals. So when the client accepts a proposal he has to flag this proposal " accepted ". what I want to do is when the client flags the proposal, he get redirected to a payment page to make the prepayement required by the freelancer. if the payment is successful the freelancer is noticed, if not the flag is cancelled.

Comment: sorry, what i mean by the payment is successful, when the payment gateway return a "sucess" status of the payment.

Comment: @YounesTechLab your question is not clear enough I answer it, please provide better question or explain more, Do you want set  a flag field and when user payment completed successfully flag field set success and if payment not successful it not flagged?

Answer (score 0):

At least a partial answer could be to use Commerce in order to [pay for access to a node](https://commerceguys.com/blog/selling-node-access-drupal-commerce). A user who clicks the link will be sent to the pay page, and upon completion of payment, the user will be assigned the role which can "flag" that proposal.

I'm not sure this would end up using the flag module, but you could theme it to look flag-ish.